# What is the fastest way to replace byte in List<int> bytes in Dart Flutter?

Tags: for-loop, replace, dart, byte

I am trying to replace a byte from List bytes. And if data is big it take some time to replace it.

What is the fastest way to replace byte in List bytes in Dart Flutter?

**Here is a example:**

```
  String foo = 'çÇöÖşŞiİüÜğĞıI';
  List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(foo);
  print("bytes: $bytes");

  for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    int byte = bytes[i];
    if (byte == 196) {
      bytes[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  print("bytes: $bytes");
```